# Why my simple python code isn't working, what am I missing?

Tags: python

I started to learn python at replit a few weeks ago. The task is to write a program that will ask you to enter the name of your class, the maximum score possible, and your own score. Than print out how many % you got and your grade in float rounded at two decimals.

The code itself works fine. But I can't get the final result in % get to be rounded. Please help me finish it and point out where I was wrong in my code.

---

```
#intro
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m")
print("Exam Grade Calculator")
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m")
print()

#main
name_of_exam = input("What is the name of your exam?: ")
max_score = int(input("What was the maximum score?: "))
score = int(input("What was your score?: "))
print()

result = score / max_score
percent = round(result * 100, 2)

if percent >= 90:
  grade = "A+"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

elif percent >= 80 and percent < 90:
  grade = "A-"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

elif percent >= 70 and percent < 80:
  grade = "B"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

elif percent >= 60 and percent < 70:
  grade = "C"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

elif percent >= 50 and percent < 60:
  grade = "D"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

else:
  grade = "F"
  print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade)

#outro
print()
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m"
```

- 

I've tried to change the calculation to be instead of this:

```
result = score / max_score
percent = round(result * 100, 2)
```

this:

```
result = score / max_score
percent = result * 100
round(percent, 2)
```

Than switch the round line (3rd) with percent calculation (2nd) just to see what it will do. Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Just as a sidenote, your whole monstrous `if` statement can be simplified to a loop, for example
```
thresholds = [(90, "A+"), (80, "A-"), (70, "B"), (60, "C"), (50, "D"), (0, "F")] for threshold, grade in thresholds: if percent >= threshold: print("You got", percent, "which is a", grade) break
```

Comment: Why do you think that the `round` function does not round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format(percent, ".2f") + "%"`. You can specify as many as decimals you want to be printed by replacing `2` next to `f`.

Comment: Thank you once more, you saved me! Idk why that round function didn't work out for me coz in the lesson he teaches it like that.  Your way is great, I will remember it for future problems. Have a good day!

Comment: Glad I helped @George! Would you consider accepting my answer as the solution now that it solves your problem?

Comment: Yea, for sure! Should I click on something? I was searching for some icon to accept it, but found just a flag for reporting :d

Comment: There is a *grey* tick-mark right next to the vote section in my answer. You click that. Tell me if you can't find it. :) @George

Answer (score 1):

Using an f-string to format the output percentage would be ideal.

Also, this kind of thing is well suited to being "table driven". Something like this:

```
GRADES = [
    (90, 'A+'),
    (80, 'A-'),
    (70, 'B'),
    (60, 'C'),
    (50, 'D'),
  ]
# intro
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m")
print("Exam Grade Calculator")
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m")
print()

# main
name_of_exam = input("What is the name of your exam?: ")
max_score = int(input("What was the maximum score?: "))
score = int(input("What was your score?: "))
print()

result = score / max_score
percent = round(result * 100, 2)

for p, g in GRADES:
    if percent > p:
        grade = g
        break
else:
  grade = 'F'

print(f'You got {percent:.2f}% which is a {grade}')
# outro
print()
print("\033[31m" + "-----------------------" + "\033[0m")
```

Comment: Awesome work! Thank you for new ideas how to make a code

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the round function. What you need to do is to change the way the variable is printed, not touching the variable itself. Also, in your question, you say that you need to print your actual grade as a floating point, but upon receiving the grade from user input, you turn it into an "int" which will remove all of the numbers that come after the decimal point.. so you should use the line below instead of the one in your code:

```
score = float(input("What was your score?: "))
```

and when printing the score, you could use this line instead of the one in your code:

```
  print("You got {}%, which is a {:.2f}".format(percent, score))
```

This will print your grade rounded up to two decimal points and the exact percentage, which you didn't specify if it should be a floating point number or an integer one (i.e. 28% vs 28.64%), but using the ":.2f" statement, you can format the percentage number so that it is rounded up to two decimal points to. too. good luck.

Comment: Thank you! It's nice that we can make the code in more ways

Comment: yes. this is one of the easiest ways i've seen. but i'd suggest you check your assignment again to see if it wants the percentage as an int or a float. i can help you further if i know the answer to that.

Comment: Idk about the type the want, but this was written in the assignment: You will need to divide to determine the total score the user received. Don't forget to round. - So I think that it should be probably a float coz of the division, but don't know if I'm right with that

Comment: I think what they want is a percentage up to two decimal points. and the score itself turned into an American-style grade (A+, A-, C+). So to get the percentage, this is the proper code: `percent = (score / max_score) * 100` Do not forget the parentheses. this will give you a floating point number which you can use {:.2f} to round it up when printing. pay attention to the syntax. format is a method of a string. if the answer helped, please do not forget to choose it as the accepted answer. good luck.

Comment: Thank you once again, this makes much more sence now for me